# Starting Tomcat 6 on Plesk 11.5 Linux

Tags: tomcat6, plesk

I've been searching without luck for a way to get tomcat running on my server. It a linux server with Plesk 11.5 and tomcat 6. I've followed many instructions but this one has pictures that are current: [guide](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Plesk/how-do-i-setup-tomcat-within-plesk-3992/). I get to about step 4 but the start button is grayed out.

I am trying to upload and run a java application from a .WAR file, but this is the first step. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, I'd try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: @admdrew Worth a shot, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that 1&1 has different licenses. My license was a power user while I needed something stronger. Either way, checked my license and Java Application was "Off". Hope this helps someone else with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

As I know domain name where Tomcat application installed must has DNS resolving from this server.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. The problem is that plesk will not let me start tomcat in the first place. I am heading up a possible license issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need the 'Power Pack' license add-on to enable this (Power User only refers to the UI mode: i.e. Power User or Service Provider).

See http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/power-pack/ (of course you can buy the license upgrade from your hosting provider - only via Parallels directly if that's where you buy your actual key from in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, you need the Power Pack to be able to manage Tomcat on Plesk.  See parallels knowledgeable:

http://kb.parallels.com/119012

> "Java Application" is not enabled in the license. You may verify this at Tools & Settings > License Management: